# symfony2 does not work fresh install

Tags: php, apache, symfony, xampp

I downloaded symfony2 using composer

```
 composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.5.*"
```

When I start it from the command line

```
 php bin/console server:run
```

It displays

```
 Server running on http://localhost:8000
```

but when I visit the url nothing appear.

In the log file this is what gets written

```
[09-Jul-2014 14:04:51 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php:32
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher.php(106): appProdUrlMatcher->match('/')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Routing\Router.php(233): Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php(125): Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#3 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symf in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php on line 32
```

Comment: have you tried running `app_dev.php` instead?

Comment: it doesnt get loaded.  http://127.0.0.1/myproject/web/app_dev.php

Comment: I'm sure that a typo, but did you put **port number**: 127.0.0.1:8000 ?

Comment: Have you tried localhost instead on 127.0.0.1 also I'm sure you should be visting config.PHP first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException` means undefined route name. It looks like you've got somewhere in your error template `{{ path('wrong_route') }}`.

If not there many other possibilities : vendor, cache or configuration issues.

### For vendor try :

- Remove all folders in your `/vendor`
- Run in terminal : `composer update`

### For cache :

- Delete your `app/cache/dev` and `app/cache/prod` folders manually
- Run in terminal : `php app/console cache:clear`
- Run in terminal : `php app/console assetic:dump`

### For configuration

- **Issue with .htaccess**

  Check your `web/.htaccess` file, it must look like that :

  ```
  DirectoryIndex app.php

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
      RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

      RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
      RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
      RewriteRule .? - [L]

      RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
      <IfModule mod_alias.c>
          RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
      </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  ```

  And check in your Apache configuration if `mod_rewrite` Apache module is enabled.
  To activate the module, the following line in `httpd.conf` needs to be active:

  ```
  LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
  ```
- **Issue with timezone**

  It seems you're using Europe/Berlin time so make sure there is this line in your `php.ini` : `date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"`
  If not write it.
  If still doesn't work add this following lines in your `app/AppKernel.php` before clear your cache again :

  ```
  public function init()
  {
      date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Berlin' );
      parent::init();
  }
  ```